Display option not working in QGIS
I wanted to use the Display option for points. I have activated it in View; I aspected a default display but nothing happened overing the points. Then, in Property - Display fields I change the default Name field and then I tried with some HTML code. Non preview available, no error messages,  nothing happened. I close the QGIS session 2 or 3 times and I repeated the actions with the same (null) results.
How can I make this work?
Installation:
QGIS version
3.34.7-Prizren
QGIS code revision
6f7d735c
Qt version
5.15.13
Python version
3.12.3
GDAL/OGR version
3.9.0
PROJ version
9.4.0
EPSG Registry database version
v11.004 (2024-02-24)
GEOS version
3.12.1-CAPI-1.18.1
SQLite version
3.45.1
PDAL version
2.6.3
PostgreSQL client version
16.2
SpatiaLite version
5.1.0
QWT version
6.2.0
QScintilla2 version
2.14.1
OS version
Windows 10 Version 2009
Active Python plugins
geocsv-main
1.0
gna
1.2.9
GpxSegmentImporter
2.5
ImportPhotos
3.0.6
kmltools
3.1.33
latlontools
3.6.20
naficp
1.0
OSMDownloader
1.0.3
qfieldsync
v4.9.1
Qgis2threejs
2.7.3
QuickOSM
2.2.3
quick_map_services
0.19.34
db_manager
0.1.20
processing
2.12.99
